# "does not live long enough" error in same function

Tags: rust

I expected this code to work because all bindings are in the same scope:

```
fn main() {
    let mut foobar = vec!["foo"];
    let bar = "bar".to_string();
    foobar.push(&bar);
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
error: `bar` does not live long enough
 --> baz.rs:4:18
  |>
4 |>     foobar.push(&bar);
  |>                  ^^^
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 2:33...
 --> baz.rs:2:34
  |>
2 |>     let mut foobar = vec!["foo"];
  |>                                  ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 1 at 3:32
 --> baz.rs:3:33
  |>
3 |>     let bar = "bar".to_string();
  |>                                 ^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variables declared in the same block are dropped in the reverse order that they are declared.  In your code, `bar` is dropped before `foobar`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut foobar = vec!["foo"]; // <---------| 0
    let bar = "bar".to_string();  // <--| 1    |
    foobar.push(&bar);            //    | bar  | foobar
                                  // <--|      |
                                  // <---------|
    // In the error message
    // 0 is called "block suffix following statement 0", and
    // 1 is called "block suffix following statement 1"
}
```

You are pushing a *reference* to `bar` in `foobar`, so you have to ensure that `bar` lives at least as long as `foobar`. But because `bar` is declared after `foobar`, `bar`'s lifetime is actually shorter than `foobar`'s, which means that `foobar` contains a dangling reference for a short moment.

To make the code compile, declare `bar` before `foobar`:

```
fn main() {
    let bar = "bar".to_string();
    let mut foobar = vec!["foo"];
    foobar.push(&bar);
}
```

or opt in to [non-lexical lifetimes](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2094-nll.md):

```
#![feature(nll)]

fn main() {
    let mut foobar = vec!["foo"];
    let bar = "bar".to_string();
    foobar.push(&bar);
}
```

Although this still has a dangling reference, it doesn't matter because dropping a reference does nothing; the `Vec` doesn't need to use the value of the references it contains when it's dropped.

Comment: For others stumbling on this issue, I recommend reading https://aochagavia.github.io/blog/exploring-rusts-unspecified-drop-order/